# Replace void to int int C++ source code file by using Python

Tags: python, nlp

I'm have a massive set of files, which are simple C++ programs, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int n,a[100],i;
    void fen(int a[],int x);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    fen(a,n);
}
void fen(int a[],int x)
{
    int k,b=2,c,t;
    int look(int x,int y);
    for(k=0;k<x;k++)
    {
        c=a[k];
        t=look(c,b);
        printf("%d\n",t);
    }
}
int look(int x,int y)
{
    int total=1,p;
    if(x/y==0)
    {   return 0;}
    else
    {
        for(p=y;p<x;p++)
        {
            if(x%p==0)
            {
                total=total+look(x/p,p);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Since this program cannot be compiled, because it should be `int main` and `return 0`. In this case, just view the source code file as text, how can i use some NLP techniques in python to replace `void` to `int` and add a `return` statement at the end of the main function?.

The difficult part here is to detect which **closed curly bracket** belong to the main function and add the return statement before it when iterating through each line of the file. Is there any fast way to do this?

Comment: You don't need nlp just a c++ parser. But you don't need return 0 in `main`, I think the spec allows main function to not return explicitly

Comment: return 0 or 1 or whatever, since I just want each of the files in my dataset can be compiled without error for my research purpose

Comment: There are several [C parsers for Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+c+parser) that could make this task easier.

Comment: @xtiger your files will compile without an error if you omit return in main

Comment: @JuniorCompressor ahh i see, thanks , don't even think it's simple like that since I don't have much knowledge in C++, please write an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: No need. Also don't restrict to python. Search for simple text substitution(`void main` to `int main`) for a massive number of files using any tool like `sed` or `awk`

Comment: ok will have a look on it , thanks